# Serailize list of generic type List<T> for RestController in java using jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I want to know if is it possible to have list of generic type as a return of a controller method.I tried it but i got serialisation problems with jackson.
Is there any sollution for that?
This is my method:

```
@GetMapping(path = "parse", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public  List<T> parseFichier(
            @RequestParam String processus, 
            @RequestParam String nomFichier) throws ReaderFichierGdaException, ParsingProblemException, IOException {
        List<T> test = this.reader.parser(nomFichier, ConstantesNuc.XLSX_EXT);
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: `this.reader.parser` returns `List<T>`? where is `T` declared? What error you get?

Comment: What kind of problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type parameter in method syntax

```
@GetMapping(path = "parse", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public  <T> List<T> parseFichier(
        @RequestParam String processus, 
        @RequestParam String nomFichier) throws ReaderFichierGdaException, ParsingProblemException, IOException {
    List<T> test = this.reader.parser(nomFichier, ConstantesNuc.XLSX_EXT);
    return test;
}
```

But adding it will not solve the issue, there will be a compile time error saying

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that type conforms to T inference variable E has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T lower bounds: type

If you want to return any type of serializable object i will recommend to use wildcard `?` or `Object`

```
@GetMapping(path = "parse", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public List<?> parseFichier(
        @RequestParam String processus, 
        @RequestParam String nomFichier) throws ReaderFichierGdaException, ParsingProblemException, IOException {
    List<T> test = this.reader.parser(nomFichier, ConstantesNuc.XLSX_EXT);
    return test;
}

@GetMapping(path = "parse", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public List<Object> parseFichier(
        @RequestParam String processus, 
        @RequestParam String nomFichier) throws ReaderFichierGdaException, ParsingProblemException, IOException {
    List<T> test = this.reader.parser(nomFichier, ConstantesNuc.XLSX_EXT);
    return test;
}
```

If you have any specific bounded  serializable class for parent class the you can also use [upper bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

```
    @GetMapping(path = "parse", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public List<? extends Parent> parseFichier(
        @RequestParam String processus, 
        @RequestParam String nomFichier) throws ReaderFichierGdaException, ParsingProblemException, IOException {
    List<T> test = this.reader.parser(nomFichier, ConstantesNuc.XLSX_EXT);
    return test;
}
```